# Airflow task status is failed but the task is running

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

One of my DAGs is shown as success but one task is failed. But this task is still running. The task which should run after it is already finished and a success. When the "failed" task is really finished (it triggers a Dataproc batch so you can see when its done) it appears as success.

What could be the reason the task shown as failed and why does the task after it runs before?

That happening after the upgrade from composer-2.0.23-airflow-2.2.5 to composer-2.4.0-airflow-2.5.3

Checked the DAG configuration but everything seams correct

Comment: Can you please share your dag and tasks code